# Cannot convert type 'T' to bool

Tags: c#

Basically I'm having these errors where the code is in bold:

```
Cannot convert type 'T' to bool
Cannot convert type 'T' to string x2
Cannot convert type 'T' to byte[]
Cannot convert type 'T' to byte
```

I've been looking all over google and cannot seem to find a way around this, thanks in advance

```
public void Append<T>(T value, bool littleEndian = false)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Type t = typeof(T);
            if (!this.IsValidType(t))
            {
                throw new Exception("msg_t.AppendMessage: Invalid type!");
            }
            if (t == typeof(bool))
            {
                ((XDevkit.IXboxConsole) this.XboxConsole).WriteInt32(this.DataBuffer + this.MessageLength, ***((bool) value)*** ? 1 : 0);
                this.MessageLength += 4;
            }
            else if (t == typeof(string))
            {
                ((XDevkit.IXboxConsole) this.XboxConsole).WriteString(this.DataBuffer + this.MessageLength, ***(string) value)***;
                this.MessageLength += (uint) Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(***(string) value)***.Length;
            }
            else if (t == typeof(byte[]))
            {
                byte[] data = ***(byte[]) value***;
                ((XDevkit.IXboxConsole) this.XboxConsole).SetMemory(this.DataBuffer + this.MessageLength, data);
                this.MessageLength += (uint) data.Length;
            }
            else if (t == typeof(byte))
            {
                ((XDevkit.IXboxConsole) this.XboxConsole).WriteByte(this.DataBuffer + this.MessageLength, ***(byte) value***);
                this.MessageLength++;
            }
            else
            {
                byte[] array = (byte[]) typeof(BitConverter).GetMethod("GetBytes", new System.Type[] { value.GetType() }).Invoke(null, new object[] { value });
                if (!littleEndian)
                {
                    Array.Reverse(array);
                }
                ((XDevkit.IXboxConsole) this.XboxConsole).SetMemory(this.DataBuffer + this.MessageLength, array);
                this.MessageLength += (uint) array.Length;
            }
            this.UpdateOverflowedBoolean();
        }
        catch
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Error when writing stats!", "GHOSTS", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Hand) == DialogResult.Retry)
            {
                this.Append<T>(value, littleEndian);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: that method doesn't look like generic to me

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately the rules for generic conversions in C# don't allow for this directly, but you can go via `object`. For example:

```
byte[] data = (byte[]) (object) value;
```

However, you might consider whether it's really appropriate for this to be a generic method anyway... it's not like it copes with *all* types, or does exactly the same thing for all of the types that it *does* accept.

I'd also strongly recommend extracting the expression `((XDevkit.IXboxConsole) this.XboxConsole)` which is used in all the success cases.

Comment: Do you have a more deep explanation about this obligatory conversion? Why is it necessary to use (object) every time, shouldn't a generic type be always an object?

Comment: @Sam: No - it could be a value type for example. I'll try to add more detail when I have time.

Comment: I tried using enums and structs(also native) but all the times it converts the param successfully into an object with (object).

Comment: @Sam: Yes, because that boxes. The point is that there just isn't a conversion from `T` to some arbitrary type, because `T` might be a value type.

Comment: If you put this code in to LinqPad you get a runtime error of e.g. `InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Byte[]'.`

Comment: @AdamBaxter: Well you do if it was originally an `int`, yes. You won't get that exception if the value is actually a `byte[]`. The intention is for this code to just replace the casting part - the part checking the type of `T` is still needed.